# Bit twiddling to get sign bit of 32 bit int

Tags: bit-manipulation

I would like to convert

```
(n < 0 ? 1 : 0)
```

into bit twiddling (assuming 2s complement arch).

for performance reasons.

Comment: Are unsigned shifts allowed?

Comment: Do you not trust your compiler?

Comment: Yes, unsigned shifts are allowed.

Comment: On various architectures, this may already translate into a single instruction. How did you established that this is a performance bottleneck for your app and have you checked what it translates to on relevant target systems?

Comment: @Jacko: In that case try `(unsigned T)n >> ((sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT - 1)`, where T is the type of `n`. Note that shifts are not always the fastest instructions, though.

Comment: So, just so we are clear: you have profiled your code and the above ternary is, according to real-world data, the hottest part of your application and if you can improve that you will see a dramatic performance improvement? All I can say is "wow, you must have the world's most optimized and efficient program."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an unsigned shift,

```
x = n >>> 31; // Java's unsigned shift

x = (int)((uint)n >> 31); // C#'s unsigned shift, the casts are effectively nop
```

GCC does this automatically, other compilers may also. Or not. Your mileage may vary.